# Gitlab CI multi runner won't clone from Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**Issue:**

Gitlab CI Multi Runner won't clone a repository correctly so I can't start my build process

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.3.2 (0323456)
Using Shell executor...
Running on tests-iMac.local...
Cloning repository for master with git depth set to 5...
Cloning into '/Users/test/builds/b16789d3/0/person/project'...
fatal: Remote branch master not found in upstream origin

ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

**How/Software?**

- Mac OS X El Capitan as the Runner/Builder (10.11)
- gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.3.2
- Omnibus Gitlab CE 8.9.6 on Centos 6 (using external NGINX)
- Git Depth set to 5 (can be bigger, but I wanted to make sure the default wasn't too shallow)

So, any thoughts on why this gitlab ci multi runner setup won't pull?  I know its communicating between Gitlab and the Runner since we get build errors on Gitlab pipelines and I see the errors on the Mac.  I've spent too much time on it and can't figure it out!

Comment: What happens when you try to clone the project as user `test` manually?

Comment: Hey @mgansler, it pulls and clones just fine.  I have the ssh keys set against the user too so that shouldn't be the issue.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Turns out Gitlab changed the way things are done.  They added in a new http request manager called "gitlab-workhorse" (as in not directly connecting NGINX to Unicorn).  Its a good idea, but I didn't realize it was the required config path to make things work.